# Timestamp in Column G when edit is done in Column F, copy Column H and paste in another sheet and keep on appending in every edit in Column F

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

In Googlesheet's sheet1, I have Column F containing data which needs to be changed frequently. When any data edit is done in any row of Column F, timestamp has to be inserted in column G in corresponding row. Column H then concatenates the timestamp in Column G so generated with the contents in column F.Now, the data of column H just created has to be pasted in sheet2 and keep on appending in sheet2 so that a log file is created in sheet2 for every edit in Column F.

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "sheet1" ) {
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 6 ) {
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}}}
```

I don't know much about coding. By far, I have managed to create timestamp in Column G but I am not being able to do further.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to retrieve the values from `r` and `nextCell`, which you can do with [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
2. You can concatenate the values by simply adding them with a `+`
3. You can retrieve the last row in `sheet2` with [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)
4. You can append the content from column H in sheet1 to the first empty row in column H (or any column of your choice) with `setValue(lastRow+1, COLUMNNUMBER);`

### Based on your code, you can do the following modification:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "sheet1" ) {  //mind the case sensitivity!
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var col=r.getColumn();  
    if( col == 6 ) {
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     var thirdCell = r.offset(0, 2);
     nextCell.setValue(new Date());
     thirdCell.setValue(nextCell.getValue()+" "+r.getValue());  
     var s2=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet2");
     var lastRow=s2.getLastRow();
     s2.getRange(lastRow+1, 8).setValue(thirdCell.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow.. thats what I needed. thank you sir. now i can use that log file to generate useful reports

Comment: @Shivahari Subedi: Glad that it helped. If my answer was useful for you, please consider accepting it.